# What is the best method to find the text under a heading

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am working on a NLP project and I have two formats of input texts.

**Format 1:**

```
Some line
Some line
Name is <name> random text and numbers.  age is <age> random text and numbers
Some line
```

**Format 2:**

```
Some line
Name
<name>. Random text and numbers
Some random line
Age
<age>.  random text and numbers
```

What I want to do is to extract the `name` and `age` from the text. I want to write one tagger/regex that works on both formats.  The name and age could be in any of the lines.

At the moment, I want to understand the technique or library that I can use. I am using [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6) and I am happy to use any library.

My current strategy is:
 - I am planning to split each line by new line character. 
 - Then for each line, I look for `(?:names is) (\w)`. The first match is the 
 - name. This works for first format.

My current code for name is :

```
import re 
Pattern = '(?:names is) (\w)'
Text ='...'.split('\n')

for t in Text:    
  Match = re.match(pattern, Text, re.I)    

  if match.group(1) is not None:

      Name = match.group(1)
```

However it doesn't work for second format. Can you please let me know and ideas.

Comment: This question is difficult to read in it's current state

Comment: Can you give some Text example end the expected ouput

Comment: You do not need additional libraries. Variables should be lower case. Doesn't `(\w)` return just the first letter of your wanted *Name*...? The second format should work just the same, just build up a second regex and use the `|` symbol. Also, you can test your whole thing before going to python [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/iQ79eR/1) work for you: `(?:^name\s+(?:is\s+)?)(?P<name>[<>\w]+)|(?:(?:^|\.\s+)age\s+(?:is\s+)?)(?P<age>[<>\w]+)`? Obviously you'd change the named groups to whatever you're expecting to match - you can opt out of using the named groups by removing `?P<...>`

Comment: Does the <name> contains one word or can be first and last name, and how can distinct between the name and `random text and numbers`. can you post a real complex example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `(?i)(?:name(?: is )?([^ .]+)|age(?: is )?([^ .]+))`

Explanation:

`(?i)` - flag: search is case insensitive

`(?:...)` - non capturing group

`(?: is )?` - match zero or one time `is`

`([^ .]+)` - match one or more characters other from  (space) or `.`

`name(?: is )?([^ .]+)|age(?: is )?([^ .]+)` - alternation: match either `name(?: is )?([^ .]+)` or `age(?: is )?([^ .]+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5N4WN/1)

Answer (score 0):

These regex can work for you:

```
"Name is (.+?)\b|Name\n?(.+?)\b"
"Age is (.+?)\b|Age\n?(.+?)\b"
```

You would just have to take care of checking the different capture groups.

[Check them here](https://regex101.com/r/uxapdZ/3). The same would apply to Age.